# Negative match against CSV file using sed

Tags: sed

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
$ tail X.csv | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]/X/g'
XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX), XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXX (X),XXXXX,,X,XXX,XXXXXXX,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXXX,XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX XXXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXXX,XXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX): XXXXXXXX X XXXXXXXXXX XXXX X XXXXXXXXXX.,XXXXX,,X,XXX,XXXXXXX,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXXX,XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX XXXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXXX,XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX) (XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX),XXXXX,,X,XXX,XXXXXXX,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXX,XXXXXXXXX (XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXX,XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX).,XXXXX,,X,XXX,XXXXXXX,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXXX,XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX(X) XX XX/XX/XXXX XXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX).,XXXXX,,X,X,X,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXX,XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXX XXXXX (XXXXXXXXX) (XXXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX-XXXX XXXXXXXXXXX): XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXX), XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXX), XXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXX), XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXX),XXXXX,,X,XXX,XXXXXXX,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXXX,XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX XXXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXXX,XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX) (XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX),XXXXX,,X,XXX,XXXXXXX,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXXX,XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX(X) XX XX/XX/XXXX XXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX).,XXXXX,,X,X,X,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXX,XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXX XXXXX (XXXXXXXXX) (XXXXXXX XXXX): XXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXX),XXXXX,,X,XXX,XXXXXXX,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXXX,XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXX XXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXXX,XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX) (XXXXXXX XXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX): XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXX. XXX XX XXXX XXXXXX.), XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXX XX XXXX XXXXX XXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXX.),XXXXX,,X,XXX,XXXXXXX,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
$
```

In addition to the delimiter comma, the generated CSV file contains comma as part of the value as well, so I need `sed(1)` to substitute delimiter with another delimiter such as `|`.

Unfortunately, the file cannot be regenerated (to replace the delimiter with something else).

my unsuccessful attempt:

```
$ tail X.csv | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]/X/g' | sed --regexp-extended '/,/!s/,%s/|/g' | tail -1 
XXXXXXXXX,XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX,XX,XXXXX,X,XXXXXX,X,XXXXXX,XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXX XXXXX),XXXXX,XX.XXX.XXX.XX,XXXXX,XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX) (XXXXXXX XXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX): XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXX. XXX XX XXXX XXXXXX.), XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXX XX XXXX XXXXX XXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXX.),XXXXX,,X,XXX,XXXXXXX,,,{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
$
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: 1. you might want to generate the csv file with a different field delimiter or with values inside quotes.  
2. If that is not an option, please provide more info: is the **second** comma in **every** row inside a field value? If not: how can we find out which rows need fixing?

Comment: 1) unfortunately that's not an option, 2) file is massive, I don't believe it's in every row, but it's common in this file.

Comment: @alexus, show more lines from your file, two lines is not enough

Comment: To whoever downvote, please use comment to specify why otherwise I cannot improve my question.

Comment: @peter-mortensen, thanks for edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of `sed`, so here is the version using `perl`:

`cat X.csv | perl -p -e "s/,(\S)/|\$1/g"`

That basically means "replace a sequence of ',' following non-space with '|' following that non-space character"

Or here is the version using `sed` (should be POSIX compatible):

`cat X.csv | sed -E 's/,([^[:space:]])/|\1/g'`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sed -re 's/([^ ]),([^ ])/\1|\2/g'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

... with @nochkin help, I came up with `sed` solution:

```
$ tail -1 X.csv | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]/X/g' | sed --regexp-extended 's/,(\S)/|\1/g' 
XXXXXXXXX|XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX.XXXXXXXXX|XX|XXXXX|X|XXXXXX|X|XXXXXX|XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXX XXXXX)|XXXXX|XX.XXX.XXX.XX|XXXXX|XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX) (XXXXXXX XXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX): XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXX. XXX XX XXXX XXXXXX.), XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXX XX XXXX XXXXX XXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXX.)|XXXXX|,X|XXX|XXXXXXX|,|{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
and Paolo Bonzini.
GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
$
```

Comment: It's ok.  But I would use `-r` instead of `--regexp-extended` to make it work on sed from BusyBox and *BSD.  

On MacOS X and older versions of Unix it would be `-E`.  GNU still supports this option as well.